# AngularJS $resource url causes "question mark" ? to appear with no params

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have a $resource that defines a custom url for the :all method.

```
angular.module('MyApp').
  factory('Object', ['$resource', ($resource) ->
    $resource(
      '/api/groups/:group_id/objects/:id.json',
      {
        id: '@id',
        group_id: '@group_id'
      },
      all: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/objects/all.json'
      }
    )
  ])
```

When my page loads, the request goes out to '/api/objects/all.json?'. It's loading correctly, but the presence of the ? is confusing to me. I didn't pass it any parameters, so why does angular add the ? to the request?

Can I get rid of it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since angular v.1.2.14 this issue has been fixed. Update to it and have a clear url without unnecessary question

Comment: Confirmed fixed in 1.2.14.  This is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should move your top level parameters into the method that will be expecting an id into the definition of a get method. Since you have { id: @id } where it is, the resource service is thinking you'll be adding an id and group id to the call.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but that's got me declaring each of the default actions (get, save, query, etc...) separately. I also tried putting params:{} into my all: action, which did not fix it. Can I override the default params somehow?